# Java executing a SQL or calling a stored PROC to get data

Tags: java, oracle, performance, jdbc

SQL:

```sql
SELECT * FROM EMP;
STORED PROC : Returning CURSOR OF SELECT * FROM EMP
```

In java, I am using above two ways of getting data from DB. What is the difference between the reultset of above approaches?
If my table contains millions of transactions, What is the best way to do this?
I am wondering if oracle capsulates complete data in an object and sent it to java?

 
I am more likely trying to understand how data flows from oracle to java. Whether it happens like stream over the network or like a request/response.

 
Another question, If I want to keep those million transactions written to a file, Do you spool of the data in oracle (Same machine) or get that data to java and creates a file? Which gives the better performance?

 
So, You might understand, my requirement is as simple as to get data from DB and write it to a file! But my table contains millions of transaction that I am concerned on performance.
I would like to use java to present the data (written to a file) and oracle to pull the data and send over to java. This way, I don't keep my SQL statements in java files.

Answer (score 0):

In general stored procedures will run faster, because they are closer to the database engine and the data.

But you should probably take a step back:  I don't think it's a good idea to write an application to display a list of 1 million transactions. That's true whether it's a web page or a console app.

Instead, write a stored procedure to output your data to a text file. Select the columns you really need instead of doing `SELECT *`.

It should go without saying that you should be careful about data security. If they are financial or other sensitive transactions, you should be really careful about dumping unencrypted data to a text file that can easily be passed around.

Going back to your first question, and assuming your response will be at most perhaps 1000 records, you could either do the stored procedure or put the query in your Java code. If you put it in the Java code, isolate the DB access from your presentation code and business layer as much as possible.

If you have more than 100 records or so, you will probably want a paged display of the data.

Again, in most cases the performance differences for a real-world problem/solution won't be that great. Your overall design and usability will probably be more important.